# returning from subprocess calls

Tags: python

I am trying to generate some files in parallel using python. Python calls the generation command as a new subprocess. So far so good, the subprocesses get created, as are the files.

What I notice is, at the end of the last process, a carriage return is expected. Pressing enter then finishes the last process.

If I run the file generation synchronously (i.e. sequentially) with os.system(commandString), there is no CR required. Is the last process somehow waiting for something?

Thank you for your help!

Mihai

```
import subprocess
for trace in traces:
    ... # build commandString containing the in- and output filename
    from subprocess import Popen
    p = Popen(commandString)
```

Comment: `check_call` will wait and make sure you got  a 0 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I forgot to wait for the processes to end?

I modified the code, works now! :

```
processList = []
for trace in traces:
... # build commandString containing the in- and output filename
   from subprocess import Popen
   p = Popen(commandString)
   processList.append(p)

for pr in processList:
   pr.wait()
```

Comment: Indeed, you forgot to wait. If that works it means that your subprocess does not expect input via stdin. In that case you can take the shortcut via one of the helper methods, such as `call()`, without specifying any of the stdout/err/in arguments. However, this way you lose fine-grained control over your subprocess. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, only you know what these subprocesses are and whether they at some point expect input sent via `stdin` or not. If they do, you *can* send it to them.

Then, there is [an important note in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) for replacing `os.system()`:

```
status = subprocess.call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True)
```

So, there is no need to go the `Popen()` route, there are useful helper methods in the subprocess module, such as `call()`. However, **if** you use `Popen()`, you need to take care of the returned object afterwards.

For better control, in your case I'd probably use `sp = subprocess.Popen(...)` in combination with `out, err = sp.communicate(b"\n")`.

Note that `sp.communicate(b"\n")` explicitly sends a newline character to the subprocess via stdin.

Comment: thanks for your advice Jan-Philip. Indeed, these subprocesses do not expect a CR because they work as expected when calling them with os.system(). I added a comment to my original post. I needed to call the pid.wait() , it now works. Thanks!